# jQuery .when function not waiting properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here:

```
function checker() {
    return $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
        url: '/test/check'
    })
}

function is_checker_true(object) {
    $.when(object).done(function(me) {
        if (!me.check) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

var checker_var = checker();
  if (!is_checker_true(checker_var)) {
    alert('Hello!');
  }
  alert('Boing!');
```

And the ajax call is basically a URL that will return true or false in a JSON object like {check: true}.

I can't figure out why JS doesn't wait on the when function. Basically it prints out,

Boing!
Hello!

Instead of...

Hello!
Boing!

Any idea why or what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm missing something here .... looking at this code ... I think it should either log "Hello" then "Boing" or else just "Boing".  I'm not seeing any scenario where it could possible log "Boing" then "Hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript ajax call runs asynchronously. Asynchronous means your function will not wait server responded. And btw, your function will always returns `undefined`

#### You need to write like this:

```
function checker() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/test/check'
    });
}

function is_checker_true(object, op1, op2) {
    $.when(object).done(function(me) {
        if (!me.check) {
            op1();
        } else {
            op2();
        }
    });
}

var checker_var = checker();

is_checker_true(checker_var, function(){
    alert('Hello!');
}, function(){
    alert('Boing!');
});
```

Comment: If my goal is to check if the checker returns true, then submit a form is this the only way to go about it? That's what originally led me to research .when in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Because your return statements aren't turned as the result of your `is_checker_true`.  When you're within a closure ( i.e, `$.when(object).done(function(me) {` ), what you return there is not directly returned within the outter-scope method (`is_checker_true()`).

try putting your alerts within the `if (!me.check) {` check instead and it should work as expected.

```
function checker() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/test/check'
    });
}

function is_checker_true(object) {
    $.when(object).done(function(me) {
        if (!me.check) {
           alert( '!me.check' );
        } else {
          alert('Boing!');
        }
    });
}

var checker_var = checker();
is_checker_true( checker_var );
alert('Hello!');
```